# Error converting date type in MySQL (ERROR 1411)

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I have this column called as "orderdate" that has varchar data type. I want to convert it to date using this

`update january_2019 set orderdate = str_to_date(orderdate,'%m/%d/%y');`

but eventually it generates error

```
Error Code: 1411. Incorrect datetime value: 'Order' for function str_to_date
```

Any help?

Comment: Please update your question with example data for this varchar column

Comment: Hi, example data is 01/22/19 shows the date in varchar (mm/dd/yy). Any helps?

Comment: The error message is stating that you have the value 'order' in the column you are trying to update. You probably need to check your data

Comment: Thank you for helping me! There is a data with the 'value' order in my column.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: If you have a table named that, this schema is in urgent need of [normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Comment: I have a feeling you're dealing with the value `"Order"` in that column and it can't be converted with that function. Do a very careful inspection of all data in that column before trying this conversion.